# How to make my test fixtures loaded only while testing in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures, django-tests

I have a Django project with production fixtures and testing fixtures. How to make testing fixtures loaded only while running tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put it into fixtures property of your testcase class. Like this:

```
  class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
      fixtures = ['mammals.json', 'birds']
```

Docs can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-fixtures)

Comment: But when I `./manage.py runserver` mamals and birds are also loaded. How to escape that?

Comment: Ups, looks like they aren't. Besides when I `flush` database, only `initial_data.json` fixture is loaded.

Comment: Yes, only initital_data will be loaded automatically. You can still load  mamals manually via management commend if you need it.